# pass result of Rules loop to variable to use outside loop

Tags: commerce, rules, entities

In Drupal Commerce, i have created a rule that calculates the price by adding some fields (custom line items), and then sets a result.

Now i want to make a loop (to pass over fields of a Field Collection with unlimited fields, so for each field collection set), and then set a result.

The question is: how can i get the result available to use outside the loop? (as a Data Selector value for a normal action)

Answer (score 0):

You may have success there using the "provides" key in [hook_rules_action_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7) to provide a variable.

more info: http://drupal.org/node/878972